# Retrieve all data in column1 and column2

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Goal:
Retrieve all data in the first and second column only and put it into a single variable.

Problem:
How should i retrieve all data in column 1 and column2?

Info:
*I'm newbie in python
*I'm using Jupiter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string from each column

```
var1 = ''.join(data[0])
var2 = ''.join(data[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want all values from column 1 in one variable and all values from column 2 in another variable?

```
column1 = [row[0] for row in data]  # makes a list of all values of column 1
column2 = [row[1] for row in data]  # does the same for column 2
```

P.S.: Might I suggest using [pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) if you're gonna do lots of CSV work. It will make your life easier :)